# Datepicker is appearing behind modal class

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-modal

I am having a problem with my datepicker appearing behind the modal popup. I have tried to change the z-index in the css but I might have done it wrong as it is not working.

This is the html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="startDateInput" class="font-small font-weight-medium">
                            Pick a Start Date *
                        </label>
                        <div class="datepicker">
                            <input type="text" id="startDateInput" class="form-control"
                                   data-toggle="datepicker" name="startDateInput" placeholder="dd/MM/YYYY" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is the css

```
.datepicker {
            z-index: 9999 !important;
        }
```

This is the function

```
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' });
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, you need to add zIndex property

```
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({ format: 'DD/MM/YYYY', zIndex:2048 });
```